# Eclipse takes a really long time to open a project

Tags: eclipse

I've seen a lot of questions about eclipse taking a long time to start up but my problem relates more to opening/closing projects. Whenever I close a project and then try to open it again it takes several minutes to finally open up. All I see is the 'Open Project' dialog and the only Details it gives are: 'Open Project'. Not exactly helpful :\

I'm pretty new to eclipse so it might be that I just need to turn off some default settings. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try turning off the 'Build Automatically' option. Also, look at how many plugins that project is associated with. If it is a Maven project, Eclipse will try to refresh/rebuild repository indexes which takes a real long time when you open a Maven project. Same with Spring Natured projects - it tries to locate the bean files etc. in your code base.

Comment: It's actually just a flash project using the flash builder plugin. I've also got Aptana installed. I'm not sure how to see which plugins a project is associated with. Not using Maven or Spring but I do have a little ant file that I use for deploys. I assume that's not hurting anything though

Comment: Aptana will definitely bring Eclipse to a crawl. You may want to experiment by installing Eclipse in another folder, installing only the plugin(s) you need for your project and see if that helps.

Comment: I'll have to try this. I turned off validators to see if that was maybe slowing it down but that didn't seem to affect it at all :\